# iText Background Opacity

Tags: opacity, itext7

I want to overlay a text with semi-transparent background over an existing text using iText 7. Setting the background opacity for a `text` element doesn't seem to work (line 1), I can only set it for the whole `paragraph` (line 2):

[image]

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextBackgroundOpacityTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (Document doc = new Document( new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("TextBackgroundOpacityTest.pdf")))) {
            doc.add(new Paragraph(new String(new char[130]).replace("\0", "A")));

            // opacity doesn't work for text element
            doc.showTextAligned(new Paragraph(new Text("missing background transparency").setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.WHITE, .8f)), 500, 805, 0, TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);

            // opacity for the whole paragraph works, but this is not what I want
            doc.showTextAligned(new Paragraph("whole pharagraph background transparancy").setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.WHITE, .8f), 500, 785, 0, TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
        }
    }    
}
```

How can I overlay a text with a semi-transparent background as show in line 2, but just for the overlayed text, not the whole paragraph? Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Stef. It's a known issue: currently iText doesn't apply opacity on Text objects.

But could you explain to me why the paragraph-workaround is not plausible for you?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk This is just an mcve. In real I want to put a label "Annex x - page y of z" in the top right corner of existing files. Sometimes there's content at this place and I want to leave this partly visible under the label. I some cases the background of the original pdf is already colored. In all these cases it just looks odd if the whole paragraph from the left up to this label is overlayed by a semi-transparent layer.So thank you for your clear answer, I'll have to wait until this gets fixed. In the meantime I'll just use a fully opaque background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around the solution you can use custom renderers. If you look at the `BlockRenderer#drawBackground` which is called in case you set transparent background to a paragraph you can see the following lines there:

```
TransparentColor backgroundColor = new TransparentColor(background.getColor(), background.getOpacity());
drawContext.getCanvas().saveState().setFillColor(backgroundColor.getColor());
backgroundColor.applyFillTransparency(drawContext.getCanvas());
```

`TextRenderer`, however, has its own implementation and does not respect transparent background. But we can customize the renderer implementation. We'll need to copy-paste quite a bit of code from the current `TextRenderer` implementation, but the good news is that we don't need to change a lot of code. Just insert two lines in the right place:

```
TransparentColor backgroundColor = new TransparentColor(background.getColor(), background.getOpacity());
backgroundColor.applyFillTransparency(drawContext.getCanvas());
```

Overall we get the following implementation:

```
private static class TextRendererWithBackgroundOpacity extends TextRenderer {
    public TextRendererWithBackgroundOpacity(Text textElement) {
        super(textElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawBackground(DrawContext drawContext) {
        Background background = this.<Background>getProperty(Property.BACKGROUND);
        Float textRise = this.getPropertyAsFloat(Property.TEXT_RISE);
        Rectangle bBox = getOccupiedAreaBBox();
        Rectangle backgroundArea = applyMargins(bBox, false);
        float bottomBBoxY = backgroundArea.getY();
        float leftBBoxX = backgroundArea.getX();
        if (background != null) {
            boolean isTagged = drawContext.isTaggingEnabled();
            PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();
            if (isTagged) {
                canvas.openTag(new CanvasArtifact());
            }
            boolean backgroundAreaIsClipped = clipBackgroundArea(drawContext, backgroundArea);

            canvas.saveState().setFillColor(background.getColor());
            TransparentColor backgroundColor = new TransparentColor(background.getColor(), background.getOpacity());
            backgroundColor.applyFillTransparency(drawContext.getCanvas());

            canvas.rectangle(leftBBoxX - background.getExtraLeft(), bottomBBoxY + (float) textRise - background.getExtraBottom(),
                    backgroundArea.getWidth() + background.getExtraLeft() + background.getExtraRight(),
                    backgroundArea.getHeight() - (float) textRise + background.getExtraTop() + background.getExtraBottom());
            canvas.fill().restoreState();
            if (backgroundAreaIsClipped) {
                drawContext.getCanvas().restoreState();
            }
            if (isTagged) {
                canvas.closeTag();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new TextRendererWithBackgroundOpacity((Text)modelElement);
    }
}
```

To make `Text` element use the custom renderer implementation just call `setNextRenderer` method:

```
Text customTextElement = new Text("missing background transparency");
customTextElement.setNextRenderer(new TextRendererWithBackgroundOpacity(customTextElement));
```

By the way you are very welcome to file the fix as a pull request to iText (please follow the [contribution guidelines](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md) though). The repository is located at https://github.com/itext/itext7

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexey! I'm just wondering why this is a _known issue_ (see Uladzimir's comment above) when it can be fixed so easily with just two lines of code. I'll look into making a PR as suggested.